# How to inject a bean in Hibernate UserType object?

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, singleton, usertype

I need to save some entity fields in DB as JSON.
Favorite solution is defining a custom hibernate UserType.

JSON converter (Jackson) doc recommends using it as a singleton but hibernate itself creates custom UserType object.
How can I inject spring defined JSON convertor bean in my custom Hibernate UserType object?

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be using @Configurable so you will able to autowire attribute objects even if that is not the spring container that intenciate them.

see the spring documentation : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

code exemple :

```
@Configurable
public class CSessionImpl implements CSessionOperations {


    private Touriste touriste;

    @Inject
    private Office office;

    @Inject
    private OTmanager manager;

    @Inject private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;

    private ScheduledFuture<Void> schedule;

    @PostConstruct
    private void replanifierMiseHorsLigne(){
        if(schedule != null){
            schedule.cancel(false);
        }
        schedule = executorService.schedule(new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() t
```

see in this exemble when CSessionImpl.< init> will be call the attribut with @Inject will be wired.

you nedd to add in beans.xml :

```
<context:spring-configured/>
```

You also need to perform weaving at compile-time or runtime

Exemple for maven for compile-time weaving:

```
<build>
    <finalName>OTLogiciel</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                        <source>${java-version}</source>
                        <target>${java-version}</target>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                        <outxml>true</outxml>
                        <aspectLibraries>
                            <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                            </aspectLibrary>
                        </aspectLibraries>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

If you're using eclispe you're also need to install "ApectJ developement tools"